# What Cpp compiler allows inline assembler code?

Tags: c++, assembly

Several years ago I wrote some significant Cpp code that accessed the hardware registers by a coding command that switches to assembler language. I lost the compiler and computer. Please tell me a Cpp compiler that allows inline asembler in the middle of the Cpp code. Intel cpu, Windows. Thank you.

It seems I lacked clarity in the question. My apologies. The answers given were a refresher of the code. Well done. The answers given today suggest the C++ compilers might not have been updated for 64 bit assemblers. Here is a clearer question which has been only partially answered. It needs an updated response.

I am thinking of buying an Intel i7 desk computer. I will write C++ code for i/o and setup. The inner loops will be written in assembler language to take advantage of the hardware register multiply and divide:  two multiplicands in separate registers give a double register product. My experience years ago was that not all C++ compilers are alike. Which of the many brands of C++ software out there give a good link to assembler, __asm, and make full advantage of 64 bit machines?

I feel this question has not been asked. Thanks for the great answers so far.

Comment: Gcc and Clang for sure.

Comment: MSVC supports this aswell.

Comment: I am pretty sure most compilers do. Please go through certain compiler's documentation on how to do this. Most compilers use `asm` keyword.

Comment: The referenced answer explains syntax issues with various compilers. The answer I commented on directly addresses the compatibility and capability of recent compiler releases. As my first question was vague, would you please remove the duplicate question indicator. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I once used Microsoft Visual Studio to write inline assembly, like this:

```
// --- Get current frame pointer
ADDR  oriFramePtr = 0;
_asm mov DWORD PTR [oriFramePtr], ebp
```

Unfortunately, this only worked for 32-bit, because at that time the 64-bit compiler of Microsoft didn't support inline assembly (didn't check recently).

Comment: The 64-bit Microsoft C/C++ compiler doesn't support inline assembly, and won't be in the future. You can install Intel's C/C++ compiler into the VS environment and it does support MS's inline assembly AND it supports GCC's inline assembly syntax as well.

Comment: This answer directly answers the question Patrick. I will buy the computer and use Intel C/C++ compiler. As I was using Unix based OS and GCC compiler back then I think. With Windows on the new machine, I will reserve GCC and Clang as backups.

Comment: Excuse my lack of experience with the site. Patrick's answer was useful. It was the answer by Michael Petch that directly and completely answered my question. Unfortunately Michael wrote a comment and not an answer that I could check.

Answer (score 0):

By default, C++ provides the `asm` keyword for writing assembly (bolded by me):

> 7.4 The asm declaration [dcl.asm]
>   1 An asm declaration has the form
>   `asm-definition:`
>       `asm ( string-literal ) ;`
>   The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; **its meaning is implementation-defined.** [ Note: Typically it is used to pass information through the implementation to an assembler. — end note ]

[GCC appears to support `asm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) based on the above article on `asm`, but I couldn't find anything [besides its support in C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C)

[MSVC does support assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2019), but not via the `asm` keyword; one must use `__asm`:

> The `__asm` keyword invokes the inline assembler and can appear wherever a C or C++ statement is legal.

> Visual C++ support for the Standard C++ `asm` keyword is limited to the fact that the compiler will not generate an error on the keyword. However, an `asm` block will not generate any meaningful code. Use `__asm` instead of `asm`.

Comment: MSVC only supports inline asm for 32-bit x86, not x86-64 and I think not ARM or anything else.  And MSVC's `__asm` has apparently always been kind of clunky and fragile:  [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59576185)